# Crop the image when containing block has min width

Tags: css

So I have this part of PSD template, which looks like that:
[image: Normal width]

But when I reduce browser's width to 1200px the upper image (.image-1) keep falling off:
[image: Min-width 1200px]

How can I crop the image on the right when width is 1200px or less?
Here is CSS

```
#blog {
    width: 100%;
    height: 667px;
    min-width: 1200px;
    background: url(../images/blog-background.png) top center no-repeat #f6f4f4;
}

#blog .container {
    width: 1136px;
    height: 667px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

#blog .container .image-1 {
    width: 806px;
    height: 570px;
    background-image: url(../images/image-1.png) ;
    position: absolute;
    top: -37px;
    left: 545px;
}
```

Comment: Change `top center` to `top left` to left-align the background image.

Comment: Please provide working SO Snippet to provide better help with issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the @media screen and (max-width) for that, just an example:

```
  @media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
        #blog .container .image-1 {
            width: 400px;   
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using CSS background property combining it with the background-size and background-position properties.

HTML:

```
<div class="container" style="background-image:url()"></div>
<div class="container" style="background-image:url()"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.container { 
    width: 806px;
    height: 570px;

    /* add following */
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:50% 50%;
}
```